# How to split one article into two articles with contenteditable attribute in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

everyone.
Now, I am studying attributes of the `contenteditable` in HTML.
When I push "ENTER" in `contenteditable`, I want to divide my article.

You can see the below picture that might help you understand.

[image]

When I push "ENTER" in `contentediable`.
It became the below picture.

[image]

I want to make the below picture.

[image]

AS-IS, HTML is the below.

```
        <div id="recording-script" contenteditable="true">
            <div class="speaker row">
                <div class="speaker-label col-sm-12 col-md-3" contenteditable="false">
                    Speaker 1
                </div>
                <div class="speaker-script col-sm-12 col-md-9">
                    <span class="recording-unit">Hello</span>
                    <span class="recording-unit">World</span>
                    <span class="recording-unit">Welcome</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to make the below HTML, when I push "ENTER" between `e` and `l` in `Hello`(recording-unit).
TO-BE, HTML is the below.

```
        <div id="recording-script" contenteditable="true">
            <div class="speaker row">
                <div class="speaker-label col-sm-12 col-md-3" contenteditable="false">
                    Speaker 1
                </div>
                <div class="speaker-script col-sm-12 col-md-9">
                    <span class="recording-unit">He</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="speaker row">
                <div class="speaker-label col-sm-12 col-md-3" contenteditable="false">
                    Speaker 2
                </div>
                <div class="speaker-script col-sm-12 col-md-9">
                    <span class="recording-unit">llo</span>
                    <span class="recording-unit">World</span>
                    <span class="recording-unit">Welcome</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**The most important point is that I want to use undo(Ctrl+Z) function.
If I use `Selection` and `Range` in the javascript document, I can develop it.
However, if I use this, undo(Ctrl+Z) function is not working.**

Please help me.

Comment: For undo function, on